# Downloading from Internet directly to google drive

Tags: internet, download, google-drive

I download a file from the Internet to the google drive folder on my local computer.
In this case, the file is first downloaded to my local computer and then uploaded to google's servers from my local computer.

My problem is that my upload speed is very slow,
so I would like to find a way of downloading the file directly to google's server first,
and only then downloaded to my local computer.

Comment: Look Here => There are diff ways mentioned here http://timesavy.blogspot.in/2017/06/upload-file-to-google-drive-from-url.html

Comment: https://savetogoogledrive.herokuapp.com working as of 1/.10/19.

Comment: I have created a solution for this problem, it is available here at: https://url2drive.com/

Comment: You can use google colab which is a Jupyter notebook that can run arbitrary python code
 https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WHB6B0NlAa_NUVVxkTxiGuWnqHEtdCrb?usp=sharing

Comment: More in this answer https://superuser.com/a/1777096/99602

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, then Google has released their own extension that can download
a file directly to Google Drive: [Save to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne?hl=en).
(This worked in 2014, and it's unknown how long it will keep on working.)

More information on using this extension can be found in the article
[Save Web Pages to your Google Drive](http://www.labnol.org/internet/save-web-pages-to-google-drive/27054/).

If you are not using Chrome, you could use this website to do the same: [Save Web Files](http://ctrlq.org/save/).
However, I am not too clear about whether that website can intercept your Google Drive credentials, so I do not know if using it is secure.

Comment: When I used this extension to try and safe a .PDF file to my Google Drive, it just took a screenshot of the first page of the .PDF file and uploaded it as .PNG and didn't actually upload the .PDF file to Google Drive. This is obviously far less than ideal.

Comment: That extension actually downloads the font and re-uploads. Just another useless extension

Comment: Save Web Files have deleted their OAuth key and it now returns a Google 401 error page

Comment: http://timesavy.blogspot.in/2017/06/upload-file-to-google-drive-from-url.html

Comment: This does not work as of 2018, the extension hasn't been updated in almost 4 years.

Comment: Working fine for me, for smaller files, however `Download failure: Source too large (40056 MB).`

Comment: @mt025 It has `250MB` limit for a file.

Answer (score 10):

What you want is available [here](http://www.techverse.net/download-web-internet-files-google-drive-directly/).

Instructions to Download Web files to Google Drive Directly or any cloud storage like Dropbox, Skydrive, etc.

1. Head over to http://ctrlq.org/save/
   [image]
2. Enter the download link in the input box provided.
3. Click on “Google drive” to start downloading the file to your Google drive storage. Alternatively you can even select from any of the other service such a Skydrive, Dropbox or Box and download the files to these services directly.
4. On the popup window that papers, click on “Connect to Google Drive” , after which you will be taken to a new page where you need to authorize the app to access your Google drive’s storage. Click on “Accept” to proceed further.
   [image]
   [image]
5. Finally you will see this page where you need to enter a name for the file to be downloaded and click on “Save As” to save the file to your Google Drive storage.
   [image]

Comment: External links can disappear or be unavailable, in which case your answer would have no value.  In this case, there is a second problem in that what looks like a relevant answer is buried far down the link so unless someone thinks to explore the link, it initially looks irrelevant.  Please add the essential parts of the link to your answer so it can stand alone.  Thanks.

Comment: I used to use this a lot. However, it seems the service is not active anymore

Comment: Not working. When I click ***`Sign in with Google`*** I get ***`The OAuth client was deleted.`***

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, as of 2018. Additionally, the website is broken over HTTPS

Answer (score 4):

***None of the existing answers work, as of March 2018.***
However, https://savetodrive.net/ is a neat website which allows you to save files to Google Drive, Box or Dropbox from an internet URL. It's simple and free, and doesn't involve a complicated sign-up process.

Note: You must have your ad-blocker disabled in order for the website to work.

Comment: Neither does this, the "Select a service" selection is broken.

Comment: Service is down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this site http://thoaimedia.com/save/ to save web pages directly to cloud drive (Google Drive, DropBox, OneDrive).

This is also similar to the page http://ctrlq.org/save/

Answer (score -2):

create a simple HTML spript

save to [google drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne?hl=en) is a good extension but

but scripting it yourself is fairly easy...

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script> 
<div class="g-savetodrive"    data-src="//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf"   data-filename="My Statement.pdf"    data-sitename="My Company Name"> </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP asked for a way to upload **directly** to google drive, and this is from the link you gave ("How does it work?" section): *The file is downloaded to the user's browser in parts and uploaded to Google Drive as data is received.*

Answer (score -3):

I use this extension: [Save to Google Drive.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/pacllhnfaalmndlofaggllkjdonlgjnc)
There you can select any folder on the fly where the file (pdf/jpg) or screenshot of an website should be saved in your Google Drive.

Answer (score -4):

Any browser, no need any extension use cloud transfer for google drive. It will save your file without downloading to your local machine. The smartest one.

Comment: And how do you access this cloud transfer feature that you speak of?