# How could I remotely upload rtmp Video to Google Drive?

Tags: video, remote, google-drive, upload, rtmp

I have rtmp link for an online video similar to: `rtmp://video2.website.com/flv/RTPFiles&file=/folder/video_file_123.flv`

How could I remotely upload the video to Google Drive? *— (without downloading it to my local machine then upload)*

---

Methods I've tried **(Not working methods)**:

1. **[ctrlq](http://ctrlq.org/save)**

   - Not working at all. When I click ***`Sign in with Google`*** I get ***`The OAuth client was deleted.`***
2. **[Save to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne?hl=en)**

   - I get ***`Invalid URL: rtmp://video2.website.com/.../video.flv Downloaded URLs must start with http://, https://, or file://.`*** Moreover, it seems that the extension downloads files to local machine's cache or somehow then re-uploads them which is useless to remote uploading.
3. **[Ballloon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ballloon-for-chrome/kbmligehjhghebleanjcmenomghmcohn)**

   - Not working at all. There [website](http://ballloon.com/start) is down.

Comment: Using this http://ctrlq.org/save/ ,  or reading this https://superuser.com/questions/737749/downloading-from-internet-directly-to-google-drive

Comment: @GiaRui
I've tried ctrlq.org/save and all methods mentioned in answers to the question but none works for my purpose.
I will list every method I've tried ASAP in a proper way mentioning a brief about the result of each one with my question.

Comment: Maybe to change the extention to .mp4 or so ?