# Save any files from internet to some cloud* without downloading it to your computer

Tags: internet, download, cloud

I know it looks like a copy of [this](https://superuser.com/q/737749) question, and **Yes** it is.

But none of the options on the accepted answer are working now.

Original Question (which is accepted as legit and got 23 upvotes):

> I download a file from the Internet to the google drive folder on my local computer. In this case, the file is first downloaded to my local computer and then uploaded to google's servers from my local computer.
>
> My problem is that my upload speed is very slow, so I would like to find a way of downloading the file directly to google's server first, and only then downloaded to my local computer.

---

So the question have to repeat:

A way of downloading a file directly to some ***cloud***. The *cloud* can be Dropbox, Google Drive, anything, but also preferable **free**.

Comment: Come and have the courtesy of explaining the reason of your downvote !

Comment: I tried the previous question's answers and none of them working now, by meaning that you can't open the site, they are not online anymore. I am trying to achieve : "A way of downloading a file directly to some cloud."

Comment: We can help you with a **process** of how to do this, but if all you are wanting is product recommendations then those types of questions have been deemed off topic here. The phrasing of the other question is subtle, but distinctly different from "give me things that do this thing".

Comment: Ok thanks, which site should i ask this? I ask this here because of the duplicate was here and got upvotes so it seemed legit. But you are right, if there is a more appropriate channel.

Comment: [Softwarerecs.se] probably.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Should I delete this question? Because I dont like the downvote.

Comment: You should read their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) which will give you a few pointers for extra information they would need.

Comment: But doesnt it contradict the duplicate question's validitiy itself? It was asked here, and the same thing asked but ... I dont know, you guys are always right somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be no simple, generic way to do this as for this to work requires the website and/or cloud provider to make this functionality available - ie you can't unilaterally route Internet traffic between 2 points you don't have adequate control over.

That said, the answer to this is not "it can't be done" - rather its hard. You need a cloud provider which will provide both compute and storage resources.  I expect this is offered by Azure and Google as well - but I know it could be done using AWS - ie spin up an EC2 instance (ie VM), instruct it to download the content, and save it to S3 or another provider.   Unfortunately this is not trivial.   This an even be done for free initially as AWS offers 12 months free for a basic EC2 instance as well as 5 gigs off storage.

Comment: I know these explanations are true and you are right. But I was hoping the answers be like the duplicate question's answers, that I can actually use. Thanks for help anyway. Either way I will mark this one as accepted if no one answers some working site, or delete the question itself which was a duplicate anyway. The questions will remain unanswered, both this one and the other one.