# Save files from internet directly to Google Drive

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive, cloud-storage

I need to upload a lot of video files to Google drive. The file sizes will range between 50-150 MB.

Because of my slow upload speed, downloading them to my computer then uploading them to Google Drive is too slow.  I need to bypass my slow upload speed.

After hours of research, I've found these solutions which are old and no longer work:

- https://savetodrive.net/
- http://ctrlq.org/save/
- **Save to Google Drive** extension. (this works but has a 125mb file size limit)

Is there a current and working solution to this.  Everything I can find is 5-10 years old and broken.

*I'm not limited to Google Drive.  Solutions OneDrive or DropBox are welcome.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Google Colab Yupyter Notebook which can run arbitrary python code.

Notebook link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WHB6B0NlAa_NUVVxkTxiGuWnqHEtdCrb

Code:

```python
#[1]
#@title Mount gdrive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')


#[2]
#@title Download something
url = "" #@param {type:"string"}
#@markdown - _Remote source url._
destination_folder = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive" #@param {type:"string"}
#@markdown - _Find folder in gdrive on the left and right-click to copy the path._
filename = "" #@param {type:"string"}
#@markdown - _Filename with extension._

target = f'{destination_folder}/{filename}'

!gdown -O $target "$url"
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yo will be able to upload video files to [google drive](https://drive.google.com/). You have to specify the maximum file upload preferences i.e. 50 to 150 MB. Google drive settings is [drive.google.com/drive/settings](http://drive.google.com/drive/settings). You may compress your files to reduce the time taken to upload files.

There are a lot of ways of uploading files to google drive some takes less time. For example, you can drag and drop the files directly into the drive which saves time. The [help centre](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424368) has documentation. If you are not limited to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) the microsoft OneDrive or DropBox or iCloud are also good options for the same.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Please re-read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

MultCloud is a freemium app allowing you to simultaneously sign-in into different cloud drives and move files between them without using your own internet brandwidth.

It also allows **directly** saving files from internet to Google drive and other drives, without passing through your own PC. The first 30GB is free every month for each account.

It supports all mainstream drives, including but not limiting to dropbox, onedrive, Amazon, Google, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a simple service that offers saving the files directly to your Google Drive space without downloading. You can save files of any size but there's a restriction of 10 minutes per file that means the server will try to save the file using it's high speed internet but for 10 minutes only, if your file takes more than 10 minutes then the process gets cancelled.

Link to the service: https://url2drive-asfm.web.app