# Can I download directly to google drive or other webservice?

Tags: download, dropbox, google-drive, cloud-storage

I'm trying to download files from fileshare slow speed which takes like 19 hours

Can I download these files directly to google drive?

I've seen [Downloading from Internet directly to google drive](https://superuser.com/questions/737749/downloading-from-internet-directly-to-google-drive)  but the save to drive extension has a file size limit of 1 GBs which basically makes it pointless as I can actually just download those files directly

Comment: Yes, you can use [Google Colab](https://superuser.com/a/1777096/99602)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download at a better speed than that of your too-slow connection,
you need to use a cloud server that has a faster internet connection
than your own.

If you don't have such a server, try the site
[MultCloud](https://www.multcloud.com/).
The downside is that you will need to enter your Google Drive
credentials into their app.

MultCloud
[pricing](https://www.multcloud.com/price)
is free for 30GB data traffic per month,
and requires payment for more, in bandwidth slices.

A review can be found in the article
[2 Top Free Ways to Download Directly to Google Drive in 2022](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/download-directly-to-google-drive-1234.html).